# Проблема с кодировкой utf-8 на сайте

Tags: .htaccess, apache, utf-8

Столкнулся с проблемой, как только я задал кодировку utf-8 все русские символы стали "ромбиком с вопросиком" , а ранее неизвестные кракозябры стали нормально отображаться. А до этого браузер нормально понимал русские символы, кроме одной страницы **index.php**

Было:
[image: 1]

Стало:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего редактор, через который ты работаешь с файлами, пишет в кодировке **windows-1251** т.к был бы **utf-8** так изначально кириллица отображалась "кракозябрами", как на 1 картинке (а там текст берётся не из файла, а из другого источника, к примеру: Базы Данных). Советую использовать **Notepad++**, там есть гибкая настройка кодировок. Тебе нужна **UTF-8 без BOM**